# MoveIt! Attach end-effector and fix UR5 arm to the wall

Tags: ros, moveit, moveit-setup-assistant, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am looking for a way to attach end-effector to the UR5 arm I have tried setup assistant but I have not succeeded.
My second problem is setting up the environment for the UR5 arm. The arm needs to be fixed on the wall of the cage which is constraining the arm movement.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267383/moveit!-attach-end-effector-and-fix-ur5-arm-to-the-wall/) by [raf4343](https://answers.ros.org/users/29192/raf4343/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2017-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could have a look at [tams_ur5](https://github.com/TAMS-Group/tams_ur5) and [tams_ur5_setup](https://github.com/TAMS-Group/tams_ur5_setup) for a complete urdf+moveit configuration that includes a ur5 arm.

In case you want to try it out: we use a custom fork of the `universal_robot` description because they didn't want to merge our change upstream: https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot/pull/267

To tackle your problem, you have to write your own urdf(/xacro) to describe a setup. The UR5 is just one piece of it then.
Afterwards you can run the setup assistant to generate a moveit configuration from it.

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2017-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0